# Plot discontinuous function $\frac{2-x}{|x-2|}(x + 2)$

Tags: plotting

I'd like to ask you about the way to plot discontinuous function $\frac{2-x}{|x-2|}(x + 2)$.

What Wolfram Alpha produces:

[image]

"DIY" version is below. How to achieve similar effect in Mathematica?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html).

```
Plot[(2 - x) (x + 2)/Abs[x - 2], {x, 0, 4},
 Exclusions -> {2},
 Epilog -> {Red, Text[○, #] & /@ {{2, 4}, {2, -4}}}]
```

or

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4},
 Exclusions -> {2},
 Epilog -> {Red, Text[○, #] & /@ {
     {2, Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> 1]},
     {2, Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> -1]}}}]
```

[image]